# Changing all number in an array to their indexed value

Tags: c++, indexing

I'm doing image processing with filters since it's cool currently, and one quick method I use to create filters is to calculate rgb curve profiles, so that I have 3 arrays, redProfile, greenProfile, blueProfile.

I'm usually doing this when I'm applying an effect on pixels in a loop:

```
*dest++ = bLomoRGB[top(r)];
*dest++ = gLomoRGB[top(g)];
*dest++ = rLomoRGB[top(b)];
*dest++ = 0xff;         
x++;        
if (x > 639) { x = 0; y++; }        
continue;
```

So, for each color, I pick the color in the profile.

Is this possible to work with matrix, or to execute it more efficiently?

i.e. Coding something like:
`Array a = all my pixels`
`Array b = my index`
`Apply b on a`

I know this is simpler than pseudo-code and doesn't even deserve to be grayed as code, but I still wonder if it is relevant to always maintain a loop to do a single thing like changing all number for their indexed value.

Comment: To change the value of an array to its index should just be this.  `std::vector<int> array(size); for(unsigned i=0;i<array.size();++i)array[i] = i`  Same could be done for a matrix?    Is that really all you are trying to do?

Comment: By the way, you take `r` for `bLomoRGB` profile and `b` for `rLomoRGB`, is that intended?

Comment: First one? It's a cut-paste. `dest` is an output buffer, `r, b, g` are colors from a copy of an Int32 from an input buffer.

Comment: Oops, yeah. In this case, it was `BGRA` and I inversed the values.

Comment: Let's say I'm also using ARM Neon intrinsecs, is there something that could have been designed to achieve such a task. Maybe it just doesn't make sense. I'm not an `index` savvy, among other things. I mean, swaping values to their index 128 bits at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that there are some magic operations that perform this for the whole matrix.

However, this can be done more efficiently if you write your data by 32-bit blocks at once:

```
uint32_t *dest;

*dest++ = (bLomoRGB[top(r)] & 0xff) | ((gLomoRGB[top(g)] & 0xff) << 8) | 
          ((rLomoRGB[top(b)] & 0xff) << 16) | 0xff000000;
```

Also, the code can be quite well parallelized. If you're looking for some standard way of parallelizing such loops, take a look at [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP).

Comment: Oh, exactly what I secretly expected, expert version. Thanks.

Comment: You could also use an `unsigned long long` which could result in even more speed, especially on 64-bit machines.

Comment: Cool, this code created a nice kaleidoscope! Not the good cast I guess. :)

Comment: I supposed that `dest` in your initial code was `char*`, and all `LomoRGB` are arrays of `unsigned char`. If that's not the case, then my code is terribly wrong :)

Comment: dest is `unsigned char*`, each color is an `int`.

Comment: It would be equivalent to the initial code, if I added `& 0xff` to each color before shift. I'll update the answer. And I hope that changing the type of `dest` hasn't broken anything else.